# Заглавные и строчные буквы

Tags: c++

Здраствуйте,
А есть ли функция, с помощью которой я мог бы преобразовать заглавную букву в строчную.

Comment: Есть - `tolower`. См. [тут](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/tolower) и [тут](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower), например...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::string m = "I`m BIG BIG latter, and с РУССКИМИ буквами тоже WORCKED"
std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), m.begin(), tolower);
```